# выбрать _id другого объекта при вставке нового в MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, insert, find

Можно ли (и каким образом) в Mongo как-то реализовать конструкцию вида
@a = SELECT id FROM tableA WHERE t='tmp' LIMIT 1;
INSERT INTO tableB (fields) VALUES (..., @a) ?

типа
db.collection.insert({
'title':'TheTitle',
'otherId': db.collection.find({'SomeField':'Value'})._id
})

читал мануал монги, там все какие то простые примеры а про подзапросы ничего.или в монге надо вручную все связи проставлять уже после вставки объекта?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`db.collection.findOne({}, {_id: 1})._id.str` вернет `_id` документа в виде строки. Воспользуемся этим:

Вставим одну тестовую запись:

```
db.collection.insert({title: 'TheTitle'});
```

`findOne` возвращает один документ, поэтому вставить "ссылку" можно так:

```
db.collection.insert({title: 'TheTitle 2', otherId: db.collection.findOne({}, {_id: 1})._id.str })
```

`find` возвращает список, поэтому обратимся к одиночному документу по индексу (в примере - второй документ):

```
db.collection.insert({title: 'TheTitle 3', otherId: db.collection.find({}, {_id: 1})[1]._id.str })
```

Полученная коллекция теперь выглядит так:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ca44bdc95c2f2de8583c5b8"), "title" : "TheTitle" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ca44c1ae794d54551f16999"), "title" : "TheTitle 2", "otherId" : "5ca44bdc95c2f2de8583c5b8" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ca44d2ae794d54551f1699a"), "title" : "TheTitle 3", "otherId" : "5ca44c1ae794d54551f16999" }
```